# Adding elements one after another using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add multiple `div` tags within a form using JQuery:

Below is my initial HTML form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
            <div id="div_file0">
             <input type="file" name="files0[]" id="files0" multiple><br/>
            </div>
             <a href="#" id='more_files'>Click to add more files</a>
             After uploading multiple files, click Submit.<br>
             <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Upon clicking on `Click to add more files`, I want more `div` tags to be created as below:

```
<form action="http://localhost:5000/api/upload_file" method="post">
            <div id="div_file0">
             <input type="file" name="files0[]" id="files0" multiple=""><br>
            </div>
            <div id="div_file1">
             <input type="file" multiple="" id="files1" name="files1[]"><a class="remove" href="#" id="remove_file" name="remove_file1" value="1">Remove file</a>
            </div>

             <a href="#" id="more_files">Click to add more files</a>
             After uploading multiple files, click Submit.<br>
             <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
```

However, the new `div` tag replaces the existing content, and adds the new and old `input` tags within newly created `div` element.

```
<form action="http://localhost:5000/api/upload_file" method="post">
            <div id="div_file1">
             <input type="file" name="files0[]" id="files0" multiple=""><br>
             <input type="file" multiple="" id="files1" name="files1[]"><a class="remove" href="#" id="remove_file" name="remove_file1" value="1">Remove file</a>
            </div>

             <a href="#" id="more_files">Click to add more files</a>
             After uploading multiple files, click Submit.<br>
             <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
```

Javascript used is as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(document).on('click','#more_files', function() {
                var numOfInputs = 1;
                while($('#files'+numOfInputs).length) { numOfInputs++; }//once this loop breaks, numOfInputs is greater than the # of browse buttons
                console.log("numOfInputs:"+numOfInputs)
                $("<br/>").insertAfter("#div_file"+(numOfInputs-1));
                $("div")
                .attr("id","div_file"+numOfInputs)
                .insertAfter("#div_file"+(numOfInputs-1));

                var input = $("<input type='file' multiple/>")
                .attr("id", "files"+numOfInputs)
                .attr("name", "files"+numOfInputs+"[]");

                var remove = $("<a class='remove' href='#'>Remove file</a>")
                .attr("id","remove_file")
                .attr("name","remove_file"+numOfInputs)
                .attr("value",numOfInputs);

                $("#div_file"+numOfInputs).append(input,remove);
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: This whole things seems entirely redundant as you're using a `multiple` file input...?

Comment: I need multiple input file, and from different locations as well.

Comment: And to provide an ability to remove accidentally inserted file.

Comment: That's what `multiple` does for you without needing any JS. In either case I've added an answer below showing you how to clone the content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This rather redundant as you're using a `multiple` file input already.

If you really want to do it in this manner, then remove all `id` attributes from the HTML content you're going to repeat in the DOM. They aren't necessary and just create more needless complication. Then you can grab the first `.div_file` element, clone it, and insert it before the `a` in the form, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '#more_files', function() {
    var $clone = $('.div_file:first').clone();
    $clone.insertBefore('form a');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post">
  <div class="div_file">
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple><br/>
  </div>
  <a href="#" id='more_files'>Click to add more files</a> After uploading multiple files, click Submit.<br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: It works, Need to wait for 7 mins before I accept the answer!

Comment: However, wanted to clarify, what's 'form a' in this case?

Comment: The `a` element within the `form`; the `Click to add more files` link